# Airflow webserver can't recognize Airflow Scheduler in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    postgres:
        image: "postgres:13"
        container_name: "postgres"
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
          - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        ports:
        - "5431:5431"
        volumes:
        - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data


   webserver:
        image: jh111/airflow-hadoop-spark:test
        restart: always
        networks:
            - default_net
        environment:
            - AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/airflow
            - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
            - AIRFLOW__CORE__dags_folder=/home/airflow/dags
        volumes:
            - ../dags:/home/airflow/dags #DAG folder
        ports:
            - "7777:7777"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        command: bash -c "airflow webserver --port 7777"
    scheduler:
        image: jh111/airflow-hadoop-spark:test
        restart: always
        networks:
            - default_net
        environment:
            - AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/airflow
            - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
            - AIRFLOW__CORE__dags_folder=/home/airflow/dags
            - AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_HOST=webserver
        volumes:
            - ../dags:/home/airflow/dags #DAG folder
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        command: bash -c "airflow scheduler"

networks:
    default_net:
```

I checked that airflow webserver and scheduler is running on the server.
However, when I get into webserver UI, I cannot find any dags in the web UI even if I have dag in the folder.

> The scheduler does not appear to be running.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you see when you run `docker ps -a`? That should display the running docker images. See if the scheduler is running without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default airflow executor is `SequentialExecutor`, with this executor the airflow scheduler and webserver should be running in the same host, which means the same docker image, and they use sqlite as a database (the postgres service which you created is not used, and `AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_HOST` is not an airflow config).

To connect airflow to postgres server and to decouple airflow webserver and scheduler, you can use `LocalExecutor`, in this case you can run each component in a separate container, and they will interact with the database to communicate between each other.

You can do that by adding this two environment variables to the `webserver` and `scheduler` services:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
```

You can check [this project](https://github.com/hussein-awala/airflow-server) , it can help you to create and run a custom airflow image with `LocalExecutor`.

Comment: It works perfectly well! Thank you very much. You save my life!